# Mark location on Gmap without Click on gmap

Tags: 6, location, google-maps

I am using Location + Gmap module. When creating a content user have to mark location on gmap. I want to to mark location on gmap automatically when user enter the values in location.

[image]

I enabled Geocoding for `India` and tried after set `Google Maps Geocoding Accuracy` to `Premise`, `Country Level` etc. but it is not marking on Gmap

I tried this [documentation](https://groups.drupal.org/node/19614), But map is only displaying if I manually mark on gmap. I am using a Location CCK Field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this using `hook_node_api`

```
if ($op == 'presave') {
    $geocode=file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='.$prepAddr.'&sensor=false');
    $latitude = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
    $longitude = $output->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
    $node->field_event_location[0]['latitude'] = $latitude;
    $node->field_event_location[0]['longitude'] = $longitude;
    $node->field_event_location[0]['locpick']['user_latitude'] = $latitude;
    $node->field_event_location[0]['locpick']['user_longitude'] = $longitude;
    node_save($node);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The location module already geolocates automatically. Go to `admin/config/content/location/geocoding` and make sure you have chosen a geolocation service for the counties you need.

Comment: I used it but it is not marking in map I don't know why?

Answer (score 0):

Instead try this modules it have the option same like your requirement. See the below screenshot and also easy to configure.

[Geofield Gmap](https://drupal.org/project/geofield_gmap) allow to use a google map v3 map to **input a location**.

A **quick text input + geocode** allow you to specify an address.

You can drag and drop the marker to narrow the position.

[image]

Geofield Gmap require geofield.

[Geofield](https://drupal.org/project/geofield) is a module for storing geographic data in Drupal 7. It supports all geo-types (points, lines, polygons, multitypes etc.)

Comment: Can't It be done with the `location` + `gmap` module only.